# How do I use placeholder API on UIElements correctly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, placeholder

I'm implementing an API called *Skeleton View* on my Xcode Project. Sometimes when the app loads for the first time, it takes a little bit longer to load the UI Elements, because the data come from JSON and if the user is using 4G or even a bad internet, will remain an empty field. In additional, using this API it shows like a gray view animated placeholder on each UIElement that doesn't received data.

However, I don't know how to check when the UIImage received a value to be able to remove the Skeleton effect and present the Image. I'll post some pictures below.

```
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellID") as! TableViewCell

            let model = arrCerveja[indexPath.row]

            cell.labelName.text = model.name
            cell.labelDetail.text = "Teor alcoólico: \(model.abv)"
            let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: URL(string: "\(model.image_url)")!, cacheKey: model.image_url)

            if cell.imageViewCell.image != nil {
                cell.imageViewCell.kf.setImage(with: resource)
                cell.imageViewCell.hideSkeleton()
            }else{
               cell.imageViewCell.showAnimatedGradientSkeleton()

//The placeholder still there even when the images already got downloaded
//What I wanted was, while the UIImageView has no value, the placeholder 
//persists, but when receive the image the placeholder should be dismissed.
            }

            return cell
        }
```

***That's what I got on UIImages(it has a blur animation passing by):***

[image]

The problem I'm facing is how do I dismiss this effect after each image load itself?

Comment: If you're going to duplicate your own question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51411101/how-should-i-set-up-correctly-skeleton-views please delete one of them.

Comment: I just deleted the other question, thanks for remember me. Would you have a solution for me, dude?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to start the animation when starting the download (often just before your function that get the data) with:

```
view.startSkeletonAnimation()
```

The view property here is the one of your view controller, SkeletonView is recursive and will animate all views inside it.

And then after the download is completed (often in a closure before you reload your table view and I assume that all your images are downloaded and ready to be displayed) stop the animation with:

```
self.view.stopSkeletonAnimation()
```

Skeleton view also provide you a delegate for UITableView:

```
public protocol SkeletonTableViewDataSource: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numSections(in collectionSkeletonView: UITableView) -> Int
    func collectionSkeletonView(_ skeletonView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    func collectionSkeletonView(_ skeletonView: UITableView, cellIdenfierForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> ReusableCellIdentifier
}
```

As the [documentation](https://github.com/Juanpe/SkeletonView) says (read the part about Collections to understand how it works):

> This protocol inherits from UITableViewDataSource, so you can replace this protocol with the skeleton protocol.

You will need to make your tableView skeletonnable in you viewDidLoad() function:

```
tableView.isSkeletonable = true
```

Comment: Hello man, thanks for helping me. Well, I tried to implement those methods but should I delete the standard UITableView methods from my app?

Comment: Yes, delete the ones that are equivalent to the Skeleton ones and keep the tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) to populate you cells with your data. The Skeleton protocols extend the ones provided by Apple so they just add functionalities. I can recommend you to download the repo on the SkeletonView Github then open the ViewController.swift and try to understand how it works, it is simple and will help you implementing it in your app.

Comment: I tried to implement the Skeleton method that return the cell Identifier, however I got this message: Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

Comment: You need to make your view controller conform to the skeleton protocol by adding during the class declaration "ViewController: SkeletonTableViewDataSource" and add all the required methods.